# ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'marks' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql

This is a very simple MySQL query.

```
INSERT INTO users_questions (user_id, question_id, mcopt_id,timestamp) 
VALUES (50053, 875, 3092, '2015-08-22 18:01:44');
```

When I use it I get

> ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'marks' in 'field list'

`marks` is a column in the same table whose default value is set to NULL and in the above query I don't even use the column name `marks`.

So why exactly am i getting the error?

Structure of table:

```
+-------------+-----------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
| Field       | Type      | Null | Key | Default           | Extra |
+-------------+-----------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
| user_id     | int(11)   | NO   | PRI | NULL              |       |
| question_id | int(11)   | NO   | PRI | NULL              |       |
| mcopt_id    | int(11)   | NO   |     | NULL              |       |
| timestamp   | timestamp | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |       |
| marks       | int(11)   | NO   |     | NULL              |       |
+-------------+-----------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
```

Just to make it clear I also get the error when I provide the value of `marks`

```
 INSERT INTO users_questions (user_id, question_id, mcopt_id, timestamp, marks) VALUES (50053, 875, 3094, '2015-08-22 19:15:07', 1)
```

`

Comment: that is strange. I for one always supply column names except for auto_inc ones, and I NEVER use default values. but that is me

Comment: I would expect that message to be caused by a query which has `marks` in its `select`. Are you sure the query you posted causes the error?

Comment: yeah @Drew, I know but I was never using the column. Didn't realize it was there till I suddenly started  getting this error.

Comment: Then what happens when you DO use the marks column?

Comment: @FuzzyTree it occurs here regardless whether `marks` is in `select` or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### A:

```
create table users_questions2
(   user_id int not null,
    question_id int not null,
    mcopt_id int not null,
    timestamp timestamp not null,
    marks int not null
);
describe  users_questions2;
+-------------+-----------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field       | Type      | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+-------------+-----------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| user_id     | int(11)   | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| question_id | int(11)   | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| mcopt_id    | int(11)   | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| timestamp   | timestamp | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
| marks       | int(11)   | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
+-------------+-----------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+

INSERT INTO users_questions2 (user_id, question_id, mcopt_id, timestamp) VALUES (50053, 875, 3092, '2015-08-22 18:01:44');

Error Code: 1364. Field 'marks' doesn't have a default value    0.047 sec

INSERT INTO users_questions2 (user_id, question_id, mcopt_id, timestamp,marks) VALUES (50053, 875, 3092, '2015-08-22 18:01:44',1);
-- 1 row(s) affected

INSERT INTO users_questions2 (user_id, question_id, mcopt_id, timestamp,marks) VALUES (50053, 875, 3092, '2015-08-22 18:01:44',null);
Error Code: 1048. Column 'marks' cannot be null 0.000 sec
```

### B:

```
drop table users_questions2;

create table users_questions2
(   user_id int  null,
    question_id int  null,
    mcopt_id int  null,
    timestamp timestamp  null,
    marks int  null
);
describe  users_questions2;
+-------------+-----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type      | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+-----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| user_id     | int(11)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| question_id | int(11)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| mcopt_id    | int(11)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| timestamp   | timestamp | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| marks       | int(11)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------------+-----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
INSERT INTO users_questions2 (user_id, question_id, mcopt_id, timestamp) VALUES (50053, 875, 3092, '2015-08-22 18:01:44');

1 row(s) affected
```

So the only way I can get my describe table to look like yours is if they are not null columns (section A above).
**Which means your columns do not accept nulls.**

### Edit:

```
show variables like "%version%";
+-------------------------+------------------------------+
| Variable_name           | Value                        |
+-------------------------+------------------------------+
| innodb_version          | 5.6.24                       |
| protocol_version        | 10                           |
| slave_type_conversions  |                              |
| version                 | 5.6.24-log                   |
| version_comment         | MySQL Community Server (GPL) |
| version_compile_machine | x86_64                       |
| version_compile_os      | Win64                        |
+-------------------------+------------------------------+
```

Comment: yes you are right.They are NOT NULL but providing all values doesn't help. Still get same error.

Comment: I didnt get the error. See near the bottom of my A block ... right above `-- 1 row(s) affected`

Answer (score 7):

Sometimes, when you implement *wrong* *trigger*, it happens.
So just *drop* your trigger by using:

```
DROP TRIGGER [IF EXISTS] [schema_name.]trigger_name
```

and it actually worked in my *Mysql* case. Maybe helpful for some of you.

Answer (score 1):

Column `marks` is defined as **not nullable** with default value `NULL`. I suppose that is the problem. You should assign a value in the insert or change default value

Comment: Have you removed not nullable constraint or added a value for marks column?

Answer (score 1):

The table you are reference in the query does not have a column named `marks`. First check that you have to correct query which failed and not looking at a different query. Specially when the error message say the table doesn't have a `marks` column and your query doesn't even have this column written then you are looking at the wrong query. Then check the table you are using and that it has a column named `marks`. Your error message has nothing to do about NULL or NOT NULL.

Answer (score 1):

I found a similar problem with the command:

```
INSERT INTO `rel_artsizeprice` (`art_id`, `artsize_id`, `price_tax`) VALUES (1, 3, 2.5);
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column ' 2.5' in 'field list'
```

If I delete the space before 2.5, it works:

```
INSERT INTO `rel_artsizeprice` (`art_id`, `artsize_id`, `price_tax`) VALUES (1, 3,2.5);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.06 sec)
```

I a large list of such insert values there are only some places, which generates an error. So I think, that there is an error in the source of the commandline tool (readline or mysql).

I used:

```
mysql --version
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.0.26-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2
```

Answer (score 0):

The table You had created will not accept the Null value you have to define the value of marks. It cannot be null probably you have used the not null. if you want your column to be null better use simply null.
One more technical Mistake you are doing here is defining two primary keys. A table should only have one primary key it can have enormous unique keys but primary key should only be one.

Comment: @Rohitlash The OP's table does have only one primary key--but it spans two columns.  It's also known as a "composite key."  MySQL would certainly not permit two primary keys, but a primary key can have two or more columns.  (It's best to avoid composite keys in most cases, but in some use cases they are necessary or even ideal.)

Answer (score 0):

You must use single quote marks before and after each record.

```
INSERT INTO users_questions (user_id, question_id, mcopt_id,timestamp) 
VALUES ('50053', '875', '3092', '2015-08-22 18:01:44');
```